# Specifying specific form format in Django

Tags: django, forms

I am using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) to give my django site some material elements. I have put together a form (the 'old' way using html) but now realised I need to use a django form instead. The problem is, these forms don't play well with materialises built in column system (they use classes to determine rows and column spacing). [Here](http://i.imgur.com/6eVkfGd.png) is an example of the layout I set up so far. However when defining the form through form.py, it spits out one input per layer.

My question is: what can I do to either a) get django to work with the html-defined form or b) make a 'form template' to give the input fields the appropriate classes?

If you want to see the code I can post some but I'm quite a new coder so it's messy.

Thanks!

Comment: Because I can't add more than 2 links: here is what the django form looks like: http://i.imgur.com/woXXhKu.png

Comment: Where is the code that you have problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of off the top of my head.

If you want full control over the HTML form, in a Django template or HTML form, simply map the names of your fields to match the underlying field names in the Django form.  This way, when POSTed back to your view, Django will automatically link up the POSTed fields with the Django form fields.

For example, if you have a field `username` in your Django form (or Django model if using ModelForm), you could have an element `<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40">` (that you can style any way you need) on your HTML form that Django will happily parse into your Django form field, assuming your view is plumbed correctly.  [There is an example of this method in the Django documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#building-a-form)

Another way is to customize the Django form field widgets in your Django form definition.  [The Django documentation talks a little bit about how to do this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances).  This is great for one offs, but is probably not the best approach if you expect to reuse widgets.

The final approach would be to subclass Django form field widgets to automatically provide whatever attributes you need.  For example, we use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and have subclassed nearly all of the widgets we use to take advantage of Bootstrap classes.

```
class BootstrapTextInput(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        final_attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
        if attrs is not None:
            final_attrs.update(attrs)
        super().__init__(attrs=final_attrs)
```

Then it's simply a matter of letting the Django form know which widget to use for your form field.

```
class UsernameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = auth.get_user_model()
        fields = ['username']
        widgets = {'username': BootstrapTextInput()}
```

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Caffeine, looks like solution one would fit best but I'll try them all for flexibilities sake.